# How to fadeout on mouseout, when mouse is clicked and dragged and then out?

Tags: jquery, drag, mouseout, mouseleave, mouseup

I'm using jQuery to fadein and fadeout the tinyScrollBar when the user mouseenters or mouseleaves the scrollable area.

The problem I have is if the user clicks and drags on the scrollbar handle, and releases their mouse anywhere other than on the scrollbar handle, it breaks and no longer fades in or out.

Here's my attempted code...

```
$('#scrollbar1').tinyscrollbar({ size: 790, sizethumb: 100, wheel: 20, scroll: true });
$('.scrollbar').hide();

var mouseStillDown = false;

$('.thumb').mousedown(function() {
    mouseStillDown = true;
    console.log(mouseStillDown);
});

$('.thumb').mouseup(function() {
    mouseStillDown = false;
    console.log(mouseStillDown);
});


$('.viewport').mouseenter(
     function(){ 
         $('.scrollbar').fadeIn();
     }
);

 $('.viewport').mouseleave(
     function(){
         if (mouseStillDown == false) {
             $('.scrollbar').fadeOut();
         }
     }
);
```

[And here's a link if it will help...](http://www.indoorplay.graphitedesign.com/Interviews/)

Thanks in advance for any feedback!

Answer (score 0):

You can set `mouseStillDown = false;` on mouseleave, before you check if `mouseStillDown == false`.
You can try this. Please give feedback.

Comment: Thanks @Soumalya! This does solve the problem, but creates another. Now when you're scrolling, i.e your mouse is clicked and you are dragging the handle, if you mouseout of the area the scrollbar fadesout. Ideally when the user is srolling I wouldn't want it to fadeout at all. [Check link and you will see the update](http://www.indoorplay.graphitedesign.com/Interviews/)

Comment: ok buddy, sorry for late. Can you please provide the link again? As it is seeking for a username and password.

Comment: No worries. The site is now live at www.indoorplaymagazine.co.uk/Directory/ It's not a big issue, but would be nice to fix it. Cheers!

Comment: Now, add `if(mouseStillDown == true) return;`, just before making `mouseStillDown = false;`. Hope this will help.

Comment: No luck I'm afraid. This basically makes it function how I had it originally. If you don't mouseup back on the scrollbar it breaks.